# Downloading apps stuck after updating

Tags: iphone, ios

I just updated my iPhone from iOS6 beta 4 to the final release, I restored via iTunes.

I made an iCloud backup right before doing this, seeing this is what iCloud is for I figured I didn't need to backup using iTunes.

The restoring process went fairly smooth, but after I started restoring from iCloud the problems begun, restore my settings took almost 2 hours, even though the Time Remaining said it would only take 45 min.

Once my iPhone booted up all my apps popup up, waiting to be downloaded, now I'm not sure what they're waiting for, but they've been waiting for hours.

I noticed a few apps started downloading, I also saw a few apps which downloaded very quickly and then just got removed from the screen ...

Now one app is just stuck on "loading", preventing other apps from starting.

I've already tried all the solutions given online, but nothing is helping.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is simple.

You are downloading something else like songs from iTunes match.

Open the Music app, click on store and after that on transfers and you will see what is delaying the apps.

Comment: I don't have iTunes match setup, nothing else is downloading. The apps start downloading but get stuck after like 50%, even apps just disappear.